# rendering panelgrid with ajax primefaces

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces, rendering

I have this

```
<p:selectOneMenu  id="dec" value="#{editCommandController.myCom.decision}" >  
                        <f:selectItems value="#{editCommandController.decisions}" />  
                        <p:ajax update="etat :myform:alors" event="change" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

it allow to disable this

```
<p:selectOneMenu  id="etat" value="#{editCommandController.myCom.etat}" disabled="#{editCommandController.myCom.decision eq 'rejettée'}" >  
                        <f:selectItems value="#{editCommandController.etats}" />   
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

when the condition is checked
and I would like to also hide this panelgrid when the same condition is checked :

```
 <h:panelGrid id="alors"   rendered="#{editCommandController.myCom.decision ne 'rejettée'}" >
                    <p:dataTable id="cars" style="width: 80px;" var="car" value="#{editCommandController.pdm}" paginator="true" rows="10"  
                                 selection="#{editCommandController.selectedPapier}" selectionMode="single" >  

                        <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{editCommandController.onRowSelect()}"   
                                update=":myform:jesuis" />  

                        <f:facet name="header">  
                            RadioButton Based Selection  
                        </f:facet>                    

                        <p:column headerText="libelle">  
                            #{car.libelle}  
                        </p:column>  

                        <p:column headerText="format">  
                            #{car.format}  
                        </p:column>  

                        <p:column headerText="stock" >  
                            #{car.stock}  
                        </p:column>  

                    </p:dataTable>  


                    <h:outputText  id="jesuis" value=" c est la papier : #{editCommandController.selectedPapier.libelle}"  />


                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5" style="margin-top: 22px;">  
                        <h:outputLabel value="Reliure :" for="city" />
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="city" value="#{addPapierController.choixReliure}">  
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="choisir reliure" itemValue="" />  
                            <f:selectItems value="#{addPapierController.libelleReliures}" />  
                            <p:ajax 
                                listener="#{addPapierController.handleCityChange}" />  
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                    </h:panelGrid>

                </h:panelGrid>
```

but I notice it check the panelgrid once the panelgrid when the page loads for the first time

do you any idea to make working this feature for all the time like for selectonemenu above, thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Surround the panelGrid with a `p:outputPanel`. Then, in the "dec" selectOneMenu, also update the outputPanel. Assuming all these components are inside the same form, it would look like this:

```
<p:selectOneMenu  id="dec" value="#{editCommandController.myCom.decision}" >  
       <f:selectItems value="#{editCommandController.decisions}" />  
       <p:ajax update="etat gridContainer :myform:alors" event="change" />
</p:selectOneMenu>  

<p:outputPanel id="gridContainer" layout="block" >
    <h:panelGrid id="alors" rendered="#{editCommandController.myCom.decision ne 'rejettée'}" >
         <!-- panel grid contents here.. -->  
    </h:panelGrid>
</p:outputPanel>
```

Comment: Forgive me asking this. May I ask why your solution made a difference? I ran into very similar problem. In my case I wrapped p:panelGrid by h:panelGroup and by updating h:panelGroup, the contents of inside displayed.